# Missing parameter exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, http-request-parameters

Making a request on spring boot and getting a missing parameter exception, despite the value not being missing. Project to solve sudokus

Request url is: http://localhost:8080/solveSudoku/getCellAnswer/0/0

```
@GetMapping(value = "/getCellAnswer/{row}/{column}")
public Integer getCellAnswer(@RequestParam Integer row, @RequestParam Integer column) {
    return service.solveCell(row, column);
}
```

Below is the error message:

> {
>
> "timestamp": 1567388255973,
>
> "status": 400,
>
> "error": "Bad Request",
>
> "exception": "org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException",
>
> "message": "Required Integer parameter 'row' is not present",
>
> "path": "/solveSudoku/getCellAnswer/0/0"
>
> }

Comment: What you are using are path vars. Request params come after the URI e.g. `myuri.com/pathVariable /pathVariable?requestParam=0`

Switch your annotations to the `PathVariable` .

Comment: You need `@PathVariable` instead of `@RequestParam`.

Answer (score 1):

You are currently using the wrong annotation for that. Using `@RequestParam` the request will be like below, simply using `@GetMapping(value = "/getCellAnswer")`:

```
http://localhost:8080/solveSudoku/getCellAnswer?row=0&column=0
```

Probably you are trying to use `@PathVariable`, defining templates with `{row}` and `{column}`. For that you can change your code like below:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/getCellAnswer/{row}/{column}")
public Integer getCellAnswer(@PathVariable Integer row, @PathVariable Integer column) {
    return service.solveCell(row, column);
}
```

You can check the docs [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html) and [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/PathVariable.html)

Comment: Thanks guys. I tried this before but it still gave me the error. Is there anything else it could be.?

Answer (score 0):

Using **@PathVariable** your url will be like:
**http://localhost:8080/solveSudoku/getCellAnswerWithPath/1/2**

**Your code is like**:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/getCellAnswerWithPath/{row}/{col}")
    public ResponseEntity<Integer> getCellAnswerWithPath(@PathVariable int row, @PathVariable int col) {

        return new ResponseEntity<>(service.solveCell(row,col), HttpStatus.OK);

    }
```

Here You have to add **ResponseEntity** with proper **HttpStatus** code

Using **@RequestParam** your url will be like:
**http://localhost:8080/solveSudoku/getCellAnswer?row=1&col=2**

**Your code is like**:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/getCellAnswer")
    public ResponseEntity<Integer> getCellAnswer(@RequestParam(value="row") int row, @RequestParam(value="col") int col) {

        return new ResponseEntity<>(service.solveCell(row,col), HttpStatus.OK);
```

Here You have to add **ResponseEntity** with proper **HttpStatus** code

**Here is imports**:

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **PathVariable** and specify the **PathVariable** **name**

```
@GetMapping(value = "/getCellAnswer/{row}/{column}")
public Integer getCellAnswer(@PathVariable (name="row") Integer row, 
     @PathVariable (name="column") Integer column) {
            return service.solveCell(row, column);
    }
```